# C++ Forward non-template member function call to template function

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11, tuples

I'd like to hide a std::tuple in my class 'Record' and provide an operator[] on it to access elements of the tuple. The naive code that does not compile is this:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename... Fields>
class Record {
  private:
    std::tuple<Fields...> list;

  public:
    Record() {}

    auto operator[](std::size_t n)
            -> decltype(std::get<1u>(list)) {
        return std::get<n>(list);
    }
};

int main() {
    Record<int, double> r;
    r[0];
    return 0;
}
```

g++ 4.6 says:

```
x.cc:13:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘get(std::tuple<int, double>&)’
x.cc:13:32: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/utility:133:5: note: template<unsigned int _Int, class _Tp1, class _Tp2> typename std::tuple_element<_Int, std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2> >::type& std::get(std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/utility:138:5: note: template<unsigned int _Int, class _Tp1, class _Tp2> const typename std::tuple_element<_Int, std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2> >::type& std::get(const std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/tuple:531:5: note: template<unsigned int __i, class ... _Elements> typename std::__add_ref<typename std::tuple_element<__i, std::tuple<_Elements ...> >::type>::type std::get(std::tuple<_Elements ...>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/tuple:538:5: note: template<unsigned int __i, class ... _Elements> typename std::__add_c_ref<typename std::tuple_element<__i, std::tuple<_Elements ...> >::type>::type std::get(const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&)
```

Basically I'd like to call `Record::operator[]` just like on an array. is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

The argument to `get` is a compile time constant. You cannot use a
runtime variable for this and you cannot have a single function that
returns the `tuple` members as your return type is going to be
wrong. What you can do is to abuse non-type argument deduction:

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Args>
struct Foo {
  std::tuple<Args...> t;

  template<typename T, std::size_t i>
  auto operator[](T (&)[i]) -> decltype(std::get<i>(t)) {
    return std::get<i>(t);
  }
  // also a const version
};

int main()
{
  Foo<int, double> f;
  int b[1];
  f[b];
  return 0;
}
```

This is so horrible, that I would never use it and it won't make much sense to users. I would just forward `get` through a template member.

I'll try to explain why I think why this is really evil: The return type of a function depends only on compile time facts (this changes slightly for `virtual` member functions). Let's just assume that non-type argument deduction were possible for some cases (the function call arguments are `constexpr`) or that we could build something that hides it reasonably well, your users wouldn't realize that their return type just changed and implicit conversion would do nasty things to them. Making this explicit safes some of the trouble.

Comment: @Lol4t0 The last is a good point. Why would you want to change a template argument MyT::get<i> into MyT::get(size_t i) ? Would your users really expect [i] to have different types depending on i?

Comment: @JohanLundberg Sorry, I don't understand. Was this directed at me?

Comment: Ah, no I agree with you. 'you' in my last post was mean to be OP.

Answer (score 2):

The error message seems to be misleading, as the problem with your code is pretty much clear:

```
 auto operator[](std::size_t n)
            -> decltype(std::get<1u>(list)) {
        return std::get<n>(list);
    }
```

The template argument `n` to `std::get` must be a constant expression, but in your code above `n` is **not** a constant expression.

Answer (score 2):

I think Xeo had code which did this.

Here is my attempt which somewhat works. The problem is that `[]` is not a reference.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N = std::tuple_size<T>::value - 1>
struct foo {
  static inline auto bar(std::size_t n, const T& list)
          -> decltype(((n != N) ? foo<T, N-1>::bar(n, list) : std::get<N>(list))) {
      return ((n != N) ? foo<T, N-1>::bar(n, list) : std::get<N>(list));
  }
};

template<typename T>
struct foo<T, 0> {
  static inline auto bar(std::size_t n, const T& list)
          -> decltype(std::get<0>(list)) {
      return std::get<0>(list);
  }
};

template <typename... Fields>
class Record {
  private:
    std::tuple<Fields...> list;

  public:
    Record() {
      std::get<0>(list) = 5;
    }

    inline auto operator[](std::size_t n) 
            -> decltype(foo<decltype(list)>::bar(n, list)) {
            return foo<decltype(list)>::bar(n, list);
    }
};

int main() {
    Record<int, double> r;
    std::cout << r[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Really nice. I tried modifying your code to use `std::ref()` around `get` and the return types `decltype() &` but I did not manage so far.

Comment: @JohanLundberg Yeah, when Xeo comes online he should have the correct code. At least I think it's Xeo who has it.

Comment: Wow, does this code even work? You can't have runtime values be used at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

**No**.

It is not possible to use a parameter bound at runtime (such as a function parameter) to act as template parameter, because such need be bound at compile-time.

But let's imagine for a second that it was:

```
Record<Apple, Orange> fruitBasket;
```

Then we would have:

- `decltype(fruitBasket[0])` equals `Apple`
- `decltype(fruitBasket[1])` equals `Orange`

is there not something here that bothers you ?

In C++, a function signature is defined by the *types* of its arguments (and optionally the values of its template parameters). The return type is not considered and does not participate (for better or worse) in the overload resolution.

Therefore, the function you are attempting to build simply does not make sense.

Now, you have two alternatives:

- require that all arguments inherit or be convertible to a common type, and return that type (which allows you to propose a non-template function)
- embrace templates and require your users to provide specifically the index of the type they wish to use

I do not (and cannot) which alternative is preferable in your particular situation, this is a design choice you will have to make.

Finally, I will remark that you may be reasoning at a too low level. Will your users really need to access each field independently ? If they don't, you could provide facilities to apply functions (visitors ?) to each element in turn, for example.

Answer (score 0):

As `n` is a template parameter, it should be known in compile time, but you want to pass it as a parameter in run-time.

Also, gcc 4.5.2 isn't happy due to this fact:

```
g++ 1.cpp -std=c++0x
1.cpp: In member function 'decltype (get<1u>(((Record<Fields>*)0)->Record<Fields>::list)) Record<Fields>::operator[](size_t)':
1.cpp:14:25: error: 'n' cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with a compile-time constant and still want to have the nice `operator[]` syntax, this is an interesting workaround:

```
#include <tuple>

template<unsigned I>
struct static_index{
  static unsigned const value = I;
};

template <typename... Fields>
class Record {
  private:
    typedef std::tuple<Fields...> tuple_t;
    tuple_t list;

  public:
    Record() {}

    template<unsigned I>
    auto operator[](static_index<I>)
        -> typename std::tuple_element<
               I, tuple_t>::type&
    {
        return std::get<I>(list);
    }
};

namespace idx{
const static_index<0> _0 = {};
const static_index<1> _1 = {};
const static_index<2> _2 = {};
const static_index<3> _3 = {};
const static_index<4> _4 = {};
}

int main() {
    Record<int, double> r;
    r[idx::_0];
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/WJUNM) Though I'd personally just advise to do this:

```
// member template
template<unsigned I>
auto get()
    -> typename std::tuple_element<
           I, tuple_t>::type&
{
    return std::get<I>(list);
}

// free function
template<unsigned I, class... Fields>
auto get(Record<Fields...>& r)
  -> decltype(r.template get<I>())
{
  return r.template get<I>();
}
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/8xxlf)